# IAM Permissions issue in API Gateway Deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam, api-gateway

AWS threw a below error saying the user doesn't have access to `apigateway:TagResource` permission, but when I checklist of available permissions in the IAM console, I'm not able to find any such permission.

```
xxxx is not authorized to perform: apigateway:TagResource on resource xxx
```

Currently, I've given the below permissions for that API.

```json
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "apigateway:DELETE",
        "apigateway:PUT",
        "apigateway:PATCH",
        "apigateway:POST",
        "apigateway:GET"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:apigateway:*::/restapis*",
        "arn:aws:apigateway:*::/apikeys*",
        "arn:aws:apigateway:*::/usageplans*",
        "arn:aws:apigateway:*::/domainnames*",
        "arn:aws:apigateway:*::/tags*",
        "arn:aws:apigateway:*::/apis*"
    ],
    "Condition": {
        "StringLikeIfExists": {
            "apigateway:Request/apiName": "my-api*"
        }
    }
}
```

How to resolve this, any other permission is required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the action `apigateway:TagResource` to your role policy to fix this issue.

**Note:** ignore the below error shown by IAM Console visual editor and save the policy.

```
Invalid Action: The action apigateway:TagResource does not exist
```

[image: IAM Console error for apigateway:TagResource action]